# Jersey - get parameter always null

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0

I changed my code according to R4J answer. 
I think there's something more to correct since I can't display anything now...

[result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqvyU.png) - console is clear (no errors)

Could anyone be so kind and help me find the issue?

Below I describe my project:

**DB**:

[database table "users"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWVlS.png)

**TestUser.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class TestUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**TestService.class**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.test.testapp.dao.UserDao;
import com.test.testapp.model.TestUser;

@Component
    public class TestService {
        @Autowired
        UserDao userDao;

        public List<TestUser> getUsers() {
            return userDao.findAll();
        }
    }
```

**UserDao.class**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

import com.test.testapp.model.TestUser;

public interface UserDao /* extends CrudRepository<TestUser, Integer>*/{
    public List<TestUser> findAll() throws PersistenceException;
}
```

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.test.testapp.dao.UserDao;
    import com.test.testapp.model.TestUser;

    @Repository("userDao")
    @Service
    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

        @Autowired
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @PersistenceContext
        public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        public TestUser findPersonById(Integer id) {
            return entityManager.find(TestUser.class, id);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public List<TestUser> findAll() {
            try {
                return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u ORDER BY p.id", TestUser.class).getResultList();
            } finally {
                entityManager.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**TestWebApi.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Controller
@Path("test")
public interface TestWebApi {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/")
    public Response getUsers();
}
```

**TestWebApiImpl.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.test.testapp.model.TestUser;
import com.test.testapp.service.TestService;
import com.test.testapp.web.TestWebApi;

public class TestWebApiImpl implements TestWebApi {

    @Inject
    TestService testService;

    @Override
    public Response getUsers() {
        List<TestUser> test = testService.getUsers();
        return Response.ok().entity(test).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a bit too much paths specification. You have specified @Path globally on your Controller and then you specify it again on your methods. Try to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Hi R4J. Thank you for your suggestions. However I don't think that's the issue, because even when I set the global path and then just added @Path("/all") for getUsers and @Path("/{name}"), I got the same problems... URL should be in mentioned case as follows: http://localhost:8080/user/all and http://localhost:8080/user/test right? If so, it's still not working and the "test" which should be passed name is still null

Comment: Do you know the difference which framework `@RequestMapping` belongs to and which one `@Path` belongs to?

Comment: Now I do. Actually I didn't realise that using both might cause the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing JAX-RS annotations with Spring-MVC annotations. If you want to stick to JAX-RS then your code should look like this:

```
@Path("users")
@Component
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUserByName(@NotNull @PathParam("name") String username) {
        User user = userService.findByName(username);
        return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
    }
}
```

Currently, you have @RestController on your Class which makes it a Spring Rest Controller. So Spring scans all methods and finds '@RequestMapping("/user/{name}")' and '@RequestMapping("/users")' so it binds these methods to default GET operations and ignores completely @PathVariable annotation because it comes from JAX-RS not Spring.

Spring-MVC version of your code would be:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Response getUserByName(@NotNull @PathVariable("name") String username) {
        User user = userService.findByName(username);
        return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you R4J. I have made proper changes, but I think there's something more to correct. Could you please have a look at my post below?

Comment: My question (first post) was editted since admins removed my post below (yes, I know why).
Could anyone be so kind and give me some clues?